Computers have the BSOD and we can't open the WinRE environnement
I'm am TRYING to solve how to remove C-00000291 when WinRE doesn't open
We have certain computer with BSOD and the solution to solve it, for that we need to access the command prompt from the advanced option of the windows repair screen.
However on certain computer with Windows 10 we cannot open the windows repair screen 
We tried:
F8 at the very begining: doesn't work
Leaving Windows collecting information: doesn't work even after 6 times
Force shut computer when the windows logo appear or the screen telling us to wait: doesn't work
We are running out of option, does someone have a solution, I precise we cannot access the desktop at all.
EDIT 1:
Mounting a bootable media with windows installer also doesn't work on those computer it just keep booting to the collecting information page
Edit 2:
I am out of option for this problem, I could really use an answer on this question, we have tried to update the bios and still no fixing
For reminder, we just want to open the WinRE environnement so we can remove the file c-00000291, does anyone have a solution when F8 or shift F8 doesn't work

Does the disk have a WinRE partition?

Yes, every computer we prepare have this WinRE partition but unfortunatly wont start on certain computer

So boot to a Windows 10 ISO.  WinRE should be contained on it.

That what we are doing all the time and some computer just kept restarting on the collecting information page

You are changing the boot order?

Yes, we are double checking if the boot order boot on windows

This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

The problem is simple @Ramhound, we can't access windwos repair manager even if the computer failded 3 times to boot

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

What error code does the BSOD show (both for a normal boot and a USB boot)? Was the BSOD caused by Crowdstrike or by something else?

The BSOD is caused by crowdstrike update, we don't have an error message is just windows booting on the BSOD with the QR code, unless you have a way to get the logs, for the USB key, the boot just stay at the dell logo loading endlessly

Remove the disk, connect it to another computer running Windows. Remove the files. Replace the disk back in its original computer.
Alternatively, boot a Ubuntu Live ISO, which has NTFS drivers. (But it might refuse to access an NTFS volume after "unclean shutdown".).

We are not allowed to use ubuntu, but I might just have a computer for this. I edit if the method work

Solution work as intended, also a very good solution when the prompt doesn't have enough priviledge to remove the file

Use a bootable windows installer and access the command prompt.
Repair > Troubleshoot > Command prompt


As stated in edit 2, this solution did not work for an unknow reason, the computer just stay on the DELL logo loading endlessly

Sorry, I saw that after. My answer is still valid - we used that method to fix some devices.

Pretty sure this would have work, I just didn't figure it out why it does this behavior
